# Where can one find a complete list of System Color Resources in a WPF / XAML project?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, colors, styles

I have made updates to all of the system resource colors in a style, but there are still random Yellow hover and border colors showing up on my application.

Are there hidden or standard themes that would be used if there isn't a specified style provided?

A link or list of ALL system resources given here would be great to confirm I have them all.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

All of the system colors are listed in the [SystemColors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx) class. You can get the explicit Color and/or Brush, or the resource keys for the same.

This doesn't mean that those brushes are used in your case though. A more specific example would help narrow down where the brush is coming from.